# How to select the latter row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a result set that looks like this:

[image]

As you can see some of the `contactID` are repeated with same `QuestionResponse`. And there is one with a different `QuestionResponse` (the one with red lines).

I want to group this by `ContactID`, but select the latter row. Eg: In case of `ContactID = 78100299`, I want to select the row with `CreateDate = 17:00:44.907` (or rowNum = 2).

I have tried this:

```
select
    ContactID,
    max(QuestionResponse) as QuestionResponse,
    max(CreateDate) as CreateDate
from  
    theResultSet
group by 
    ContactID
```

This will NOT work because there could be `QuestionResponse` 2 and then 1 for the same `contactID`. In that case the latter one will be the one with response 1 not 2.

Thank you for you help.

Comment: what is your SQLServer version ?

Comment: Please paste the result set as text

Comment: would max(rowNum) not work with your same grouping?

Comment: max(rowNum) helps! Thank you scsimon!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use ROW_NUMBER() that way:

```
WITH Query AS
(
    SELECT rowNum, ContactID, QuestionResponse, CreateDate,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ContactID ORDER BY CreateDate DESC) Ordered
    FROM theResultSet
)
SELECT * FROM Query WHERE Ordered=1
```

1. Assign numbers in ContactID group by date, descending
2. Filter results having number <> 1

Comment: I wouldn't use the word `group` in this context, being that `group by` already means something in SQL.  I would use the word that actually exist in the sql; `partition` - Even if you then have to define what you mean, at least then it's not ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

This might work if your SQL Engine can handle it...

```
SELECT trs1.*
  FROM theResultSet trs1
       INNER JOIN
       (SELECT ContactID, max(CreateDate) as CreateDate
          FROM theResultSet
         GROUP BY ContactID) trs2
       ON     trs1.ContactID = trs2.ContactID
          AND trs1.CreateDate = trs2.CreateDate
```

The end result will be all rows from theResultSet where the creation date is the max creation date.

Comment: Thank you for your response StoneGiant. I was trying to avoid doing a self join

Answer (score 0):

This should work too:

```
SELECT
    ContactID, QuestionResponse,CreateDate
FROM (
    select rowNum, ContactID, QuestionResponse,CreateDate,
    max(rowNum) over(partition by ContactID) as maxrow
    from    theResultSet
    ) x
WHERE rowNum=maxrow
```